# Jasmine spyOn with CoffeeScript on Rails 3.1 with test_track

Tags: coffeescript, jasmine

I'm using Jasmine with CoffeeScript (in Rails 3.1) and [test_track](https://github.com/quickleft/test_track). Everything else is fine, but I cant have spyOn on function calls to work:

```
describe "spyOn", ->
  it "should spy", ->
    foo = 
      bar: ->

    spyOn(foo, 'bar')
    foo.bar()
    expect(foo.bar).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

the expect fails. What's wrong?

Update: the same exact code works on [tryjasmine](http://try-jasmine.heroku.com/). It could be a bug with the version of jasmine with test_track.

Comment: Do you have a spaces vs tabs issue?  Is the `spyOn` call being pulled into the `bar` function due to improper whitespace issues?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but if I copy and paste the same code to tryjasmine it works, so it must be something else

Comment: If you are creating empty functions, its good practice to write them as `(->)`.  In some cases, leaving off the parens will cause problems.

Comment: It would probably be worthwhile to put a console.log in the bar function just to see whether it's getting called.

Comment: @aaron I tried that, but the result is the same

Comment: @SteveRoss as far I know, with that simple code the original "bar" shouldn't be executed...

Comment: @danmaz74 I know it doesn't fix your problem; I was simply pointing out ways your code could be cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who got the same problem, here's the answer:

https://github.com/quickleft/test_track/issues/7#issuecomment-2570580

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the compiled JavaScript and debug from there. Perhaps those returns are causing problems?

```
describe("spyOn", function() {
  return it("should spy", function() {
    var foo;
    foo = {
      bar: function() {}
    };
    spyOn(foo, 'bar');
    foo.bar();
    return expect(foo.bar).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that's not the problem. I just found what it is, I'll post it now for others to refer to